# Find missing files (dates) in folders using C# Script Task

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I have some flat files with filename includes date in yyyyMMdd format. Here are some example:

Folder Path: C:\Source

FileNames:

myfile1_20220104983423.txt
myfile1_20220104983423.txt
myfile1_20220104983423.txt
myfile1_20220104983423.txt
myfile1_20220104983423.txt
myfile1_20220104983423.txt

I am writing the following script in a C# Script Task to loop through the set of files and create a missing files list (lets say in yyyyMMdd format) based on the Min and Max Date range for the files and save that into a SSIS Object Type Variable.

What I have tried :

```
//define initial folder and extension
string initialdir = @"C:\Source";
string fileExt = "*.txt";
//needed to extract date from file name
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cu = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

//get files and missing dates
var filesAndDates = Directory.EnumerateFiles(initialdir, fileExt, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    //group files by directory name
    .GroupBy(x => Path.GetDirectoryName(x))
    //select files and corresponding dates from file name
    .Select(grp => new
        {
            folder = grp.Key,
            files = grp.Select(f=>Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)).ToList(),
            dates = grp.Select(f=>DateTime.ParseExact(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Replace("myfile_", ""), "yyyyMMdd", cu)).ToList(),
        })
    //find missing dates in folders
    .SelectMany(x =>
        //create date range between min and max in current folder - get all dates
        //exclude dates which already exist
        Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(x.dates.Max() - x.dates.Min()).TotalDays + 1)
            .Select(i => x.dates.Min().AddDays(i))
            .Except(x.dates)
            .Select(y=> new
                {
                    folder = x.folder,
                    missingDate = y
                })
        );

foreach(var fd in filesAndDates)
{
    dts.Variables["User::MissingFileList"].Value = fd.missingDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd", cu));
}
```

But I'm getting this error "String was not recognized as valid datetime". What I'm missing over here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this code I believe:

Firstly, have to change this line:

```
dates = grp.Select(f=>DateTime.ParseExact(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Replace("myfile_", ""), "yyyyMMdd", cu)).ToList(),
```

to the following line:

```
dates = grp.Select(f => DateTime.ParseExact(DoFormat(f), "yyyyMMdd", cu)).ToList(),
```

which 'DoFormat' method is as below (I refactored as this way to be more clear) :

```
        private static ReadOnlySpan<char> DoFormat(string f)
    {
        var data =  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);
        data = data.Replace("myfile1_", "");

        return data;
    }
```

This solves the problem of Replacing `myfile1_' with an empty string.

The second problem occurs when you try to format `20220104983423` by using `yyyyMMdd` and you have to consider changing the date format, renaming the file, or changing the way that you generate the files.

Comment: Thanks @mohi. I'll try as you said.

Comment: Mohi, I have tried that which requires System.memory reference which I have added and still having same issue "string not recognised as valid datetime".

Comment: Any other ideas ?

Comment: Your date string is not in the same format. `yyyyMMdd` string format means `20220104`, and you are trying to format `20220104983423`. What is that mean? It means you are trying to wear an XS size T-Shirt to a man who is XXL ;). So change the man or find a suitable T-Shirt.